# Validaciones con Data Annotations en Entity framework no funcionan

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, razor

Tengo un formulario hecho en Asp.NET MVC usando Entity framework para persistencia y usando Data Annotations para validar los campos.
El problema que tengo es que las validaciones no funcionan, quiero poner campos con valor null, quiero guardar los campos y me salta una excepción en la línea `throw new System.Exception(errorMessage);` del controlador y al fijarme en el detalle me dice:

```
Entity of type "Estudiante" in state "Added" has the following validation errors:
- Property: "EstudianteNombre", Error: "El campo EstudianteNombre es obligatorio."
- Property: "EstudianteGenero", Error: "El campo EstudianteGenero es obligatorio."
```

y luego me tira la siguiente pantalla:

```
Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.

Entity of type "Estudiante" in state "Added" has the following validation errors:
- Property: "EstudianteNombre", Error: "El campo EstudianteNombre es obligatorio."
- Property: "EstudianteGenero", Error: "El campo EstudianteGenero es obligatorio."
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Detalles de la excepción: System.Exception:
Entity of type "Estudiante" in state "Added" has the following validation errors:
- Property: "EstudianteNombre", Error: "El campo EstudianteNombre es obligatorio."
- Property: "EstudianteGenero", Error: "El campo EstudianteGenero es obligatorio."

    Error de código fuente:


    Línea 58:                                }
    Línea 59:                            }
    Línea 60:                            throw new System.Exception(errorMessage);
    Línea 61:                        } 
    Línea 62:                     return RedirectToAction("Crear", "Home");
```

Que está pasando?
Tengo las líneas en mi web.config

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Vista:

```
@model Estudiante
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<br />
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EstudianteNombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EstudianteNombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstudianteNombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EstudianteGenero, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("EstudianteGenero", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Genero"], "Select Gender", new { @class = "form-control" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstudianteGenero, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Crear"lass="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Controlador:

```
using Lista7.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Lista7.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private EstudianteEntities db = new EstudianteEntities();

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Crear()
        {
            var estudiante = new Estudiante();

            var items = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Masculino", Value = "Masculino"},
                new SelectListItem {Text = "Femenino", Value = "Femenino"},
            };

            ViewData["Genero"] = items;

            return View(estudiante);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Crear([Bind(Include = "EstudianteId,EstudianteNombre,EstudianteGenero")] Estudiante stu)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                try
                {
                    db.Estudiante.Add(stu);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                      catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                       {
                           string errorMessage = "";
                           foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                           {
                               errorMessage = string.Format("\nEntity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                                   eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                               foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                               {
                                   errorMessage += string.Format("\n- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                                       ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                               }
                           }
                           throw new System.Exception(errorMessage);
                       } 
                    return RedirectToAction("Crear", "Home");




            }

            return View(stu);
        }
    }
}
```

Modelo

```
 Estudiante.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Lista7.Models;

namespace Lista7.Models
{


    [MetadataType(typeof(EstudianteMetaData))]
    public partial class Estudiante
    {
    }


    public enum Genero
    {
        Masculino,
        Femenino
    }
}
```

EstudianteMetaData.cs

```
using Lista7.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace Lista7.Models
    {
        public class EstudianteMetaData
        {
            public int EstudianteId { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [StringLength(50)]
            public string EstudianteNombre { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public Genero EstudianteGenero { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No entendí, que es lo que no funciona? Esa excepción te valida el modelo, en el cual le estas indicando - en la clase EstudianteMetaData.cs - que el campo EstudianteNombre y EstudianteGenero **SON REQUERIDOS**, entonces la lógica de tu aplicación es correcta... Si guardas un valor como null obviamente te lanzará esa excepción

Comment: entonces que cambios tengo que hacer al código fuente, para cuando intente poner valores nulos, me aparezca un mensaje que diga que el campo es obligatorio?

Comment: De hecho el mensaje aparece amigo. Posiblemente lo que quieres hacer tú es que aparezca de forma visual (una ventana, un texto) que te indique que dicho campo es requerido. Si lo que quieres eso, la solución sería algo así: *@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EstudianteNombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*

Comment: esa línea la tengo, ya no entiendo más nada